# Match smallest possible sentence

Tags: python, regex, python-re, findall

Text:

```
One sentence here, much wow. Another one here. This is O.N.E. example n. 1, a nice one to understand. Hope it's clear now!
```

Regex: `(?<=\.\s)[A-Z].+?nice one.+?\.(?=\s[A-Z])`

Result: `Another one here. This is O.N.E. example n. 1, a nice one to understand.`

How can I do to obtain `This is O.N.E. example among n. 1, a nice one to understand.`? (i.e. the smallest possible sentence that matches the regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude matching a dot, and only match the dot incase of an uppercase char followed by a dot, or a dot followed by a space and digit.

```
(?:(?<=\.\s)|^)[A-Z][^.A-Z]*(?:(?:[A-Z]\.|\.\s\d)[^.A-Z]*)*\bnice one\b.+?(?=\s[A-Z])
```

- `(?:(?<=\.\s)|^)` Assert a `.` and whitespace char to the left or the start of the string
- `[A-Z][^.A-Z]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and 0+ times any char except a dot or uppercase char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:[A-Z]\.|\.\s\d)` Match either A-Z and `.` or match `.` whitespace char and digit
  - `[^.A-Z]*` Optionally match any char except a `.` or uppercase char
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `\bnice one\b.+?(?=\s[A-Z])` Match `nice one` and match until asserting a whitspace char and uppercase char to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9tpCb/1)

Comment: Why in [this case](https://regex101.com/r/Js7iD9/1) your regex doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @albero Hi there, that is because in the previous pattern it could not cross matching uppercase chars. Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/NCCyev/1 If you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could make use of possessive quantifiers https://regex101.com/r/6h93MV/1

Comment: Thank you. I slightly modified it but still can't match what is expected; https://regex101.com/r/lUzbDz/2

I've tried adding some alternatives in the positive lookbehind and in the more internal non-capturing group, but this only leads to catastrophic backtrack..

Comment: @albero The text is quite long, but you might try using a capture group https://regex101.com/r/Y8d209/1

Answer (score 2):

Just insert a greedy `.*` in front of the expression

```
.*\.\s([A-Z].+?nice one.+?\.(?=\s[A-Z]))
```

Comment: Nice, but what if the string of interest is in the actual [first sentence of the text](https://regex101.com/r/PDXkde/1)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little bit of a different approach just splitting the entire text and then filtering out what you are after:

```
import re
s = "One sentence here, much wow. Another one here. This is O.N.E. example n. 1, a nice one to understand. Hope it's clear now!"
result = [x for x in re.split(r'(?<=\B.\.)\s*',s) if 'nice one' in x][0]
print(result) # This is O.N.E. example n. 1, a nice one to understand.
```

Not sure how many edge-cases you have got but here I used `re.split()` with the following pattern: `(?<=\B.\.)\s*`. This would mean:

- `(?<=\B.\.)` - A positive lookbehind to assert position is after a position where `\b` (a word-boundary) does **not** apply, followed by a literal dot.
- `\s*` - 0+ Whitespace characters.

With the resulting array it won't be too much problem to check which element is holding your desired words "nice one".

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR4IOj/1)